# HerokuでFlaskでのwebsocketsのエラー

Tags: heroku, flask, websocket

Herokuを使って、Flaskのチャットアプリをpushしました。
しかし、ローカルでは動いてました。

おそらくHerokuに機能を追加するコマンドが必要みたいなので、
heroku labs:enable websocketsをしましたが、

```
heroku labs:enable websockets
 !    No such feature: websockets
```

となりました。
これは有料会員限定でしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: ちなみに
wss://app_name.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/websocket/ のサーバへの接続を確立できませんでした。 socket.io.min.js:2
ページの読み込み中に wss://app_name.herokuapp.com/socket.io/1/websocket/ への接続が切断されました。

のエラーがブラウザで出てます。

Comment: [今では`labs:enable`しなくても使えるようです](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/7/7/websockets_now_ga)。質問には書かれていませんでしたが、`socket.io`を使っているのですね。参考にされた記事などあれば質問に追記していただけると、あなたの状況が回答者にわかりやすくなるかと思います。